# Progressbar on separate form freezes/crashes when updating

Tags: vb.net, winforms, progress-bar, invokerequired

I have a weird exception that I can't seem to debug. For anyone about to suggest worker threads I am prohibited from using them at my work... I asked why not myself and received a vague answer and clear directions to avoid it... anyways...

I decided I wanted to have a progress bar on a separate form that is initialized and shown directly from my library class (independent of the main form and executing on a different thread). Even though this class initializes the form itself, I am using control.InvokeRequired and control.Invoke anyway so I can reuse the form elsewhere. 
The following is for initializing the progress bar:

```
Public Sub InitializePB(ByVal _Maximum As Integer, ByVal _Step As Integer, ByVal _StartValue As Integer, ByVal _Style As Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        'Different thread - invoke delegate
        pb_Progress.Invoke(Sub() InitializePB(_Maximum, _Step, _StartValue, _Style))
    Else
        'Same thread - set values
        pb_Progress.Minimum = 1
        pb_Progress.Maximum = _Maximum
        pb_Progress.Step = _Step
        pb_Progress.Value = _StartValue
        pb_Progress.Style = _Style
        Me.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now for the step function:

```
    Public Sub PerformStepPB()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        'Different thread - invoke delegate
        pb_Progress.Invoke(Sub() PerformStepPB())
    Else
        'Same thread - perform step
        pb_Progress.PerformStep()
        Me.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now the following is test code from where I launch form containing the progress bar and then send step calls:

```
        pbForm = New frmProgress(_OwnerDesktopLoc)
        pbForm.Show()

        pbForm.InitializePB(100, 1, 1, Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Blocks)

        Dim msElapsedVals As Integer = 0

        While msElapsedVals <= 100
            pbForm.PerformStepPB()
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            msElapsedVals += 1
        End While
        pbForm.Close()
        pbForm.Dispose()
        While Not pbForm.IsDisposed
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While

        Exit Sub
```

So far so good... you will notice that I call the Form.Refresh method for the progress bar form every time the step method is called. I ended up doing this because when the form launched it would crash after several progress bar steps. At this point in time the form does show without crashing (because of the refresh) except that if I click the form it crashes (and no exception is caught by Visual Studio). The weird thing is that the code from the library class for updating the progress bar continues without any problems as if the problem is simply with the Win32 window. Here is the Windows message associated with the crash:

**Description:
  A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   AppHangB1
  Application Name: DL_RDS_Sort.vshost.exe**

I tried launching the form from the main form thread but with the same results. I have no clue what's going on... any help would be greatly appreciated =D

Update on exactly how things are being called:

From MainForm a thread is started with the address of a subroutine defined within a library class :

```
    Private Sub but_Sort_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles but_Sort.Click


    Me.Sorter.OwnerDesktopLoc = New Drawing.Point(Me.DesktopLocation.X + CInt(Me.DesktopBounds.Width / 6), Me.DesktopLocation.Y + CInt(Me.DesktopBounds.Height / 2))

    'Start sorting thread
    Me.sortThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.Sorter.Sort)
    Me.sortThread.Start()
```

Then in this thread's routine I am testing the initialization of the form and calling the methods (shown earlier) I wrote for updating the performance bar properties:

```
    Public Sub Sort()
    Try
        IIf(_OwnerDesktopLoc = Nothing, useProgressBar = False, useProgressBar = True)

        'TESTING//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        pbForm = New frmProgress(_OwnerDesktopLoc)
        pbForm.Show()

        pbForm.InitializePB(100, 1, 1, Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Blocks)

        Dim msElapsedVals As Integer = 0

        While msElapsedVals <= 100
            pbForm.PerformStepPB()
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            msElapsedVals += 1
        End While
        pbForm.Close()
        pbForm.Dispose()
        While Not pbForm.IsDisposed
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While

        Exit Sub
        'TESTING//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Note that there is a lot more code following the testing area but it never gets called and does not play a part in this issue because I exit the subroutine. I normally use ShowDialog but this halts the execution which is not what I want.

Some things worth mentioning: 
-the frmProgress has the ControlBox property set to false.
-the frmProgress has the FormBorderStyle set to FixedDialog

Also: When I use the Show() method, the Windows "busy circle" cursor appears when I hover my mouse over the shown form. ShowDialog() does not have this behaviour... It's as if the form is waiting for something... Hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: My condolences on not being allowed to use a BackgroundWorker.  Anyway, I couldn't reproduce any errors.  Form pops up, updates progress bar, closes every time.  If you aren't allowed worker threads, I don't think I understand how this would be called on another thread.  The problem is somewhere else than the posted code.

Comment: Hi, in your test did you launch the form from another thread? I just tested without any calls to update the progress bar and the same thing is happening... which means the pb has nothing to do with the issue. It's simply an issue with showing the form from a thread that is not my main thread... which I have done countless times in other applications... weird.

Comment: Completely confused if you are - or are not - using threads. Prohibited?

Comment: Sorry... from my main form I launch a thread with the address of the main routine in my class library like this:

Comment: Sorry the above didn't make sense. Sorry... from my main form I launch a thread with the address of the main routine in my class library. From this routine I then launch the form containing a progress bar and status label. In the original post you will notice all the invoke stuff but in this case it is not being used because I create and show the form from the same thread in which I call the step functions. It is just there because I was playing with different methods. One thing I notice is that when the form shows.. the mouse pointer is in the "wait circle" mode.

Comment: Try posting the threading code, because it doesn't sound like it really is on another thread (which I thought your boss said no to that?).

Comment: I added more info to my post. My bosses instructions are specific to the BackgroundWorker component which I know is just a thread ... but he says he's seen issues with it and doesn't want it in the code :O

Comment: Figured it out: the form should be shown from the main thread. Showing it from another thread with the Show() method is unstable... Unless there's something I'm missing.